# Global shell route gets stuck on navigation stack when returning to Shell Visual Hierarchy from outside visual hierarchy in Xamarin.Forms Shell

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-shell

I am using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 and Shell feature for navigation. When navigating away from a global route, then returning to a visual hierarchy route, that the global route was sitting on top of the global route.

I set up two ShellContents for routes "Page1" and "Page3" in the Shell visual hierarchy in AppShell.xaml as follows,

```
<TabBar x:Name="bottomTabBars">
    <Tab Title="Page One" Icon="ic_pg1">
        <ShellContent Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Page Three" Icon="ic_pg3">
         <ShellContent Route="Page3" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Then I set up Page2 as a global route (outside visual hierarchy) through Routing.RegisterRoute("Page2") in AppShell code behind as follows

```
private void RegisterRoutes()
{
 Routing.RegisterRoute("Page2", typeof(Page2));
}
```

When the app starts, Page1 will be loaded because it is the first shell content in visual hierarchy. Now consider Page1 has a button and when it is clicked, it redirects me to Page2 (using GoToAsync()). So far now, I am in Page2. Then I clicked Page3 from bottom tabbar, I am redirected to Page3. Now I clicked Page1 from bottom tabbar and it redirected me to Page2 instead of Page1.

As per the official docs, **visual hierarchy routes are always at the root.**

Here it seems, route in visual hierarchy maintains non-visual hierarchy routes in navigation stack.

I need, whenever a route in visual hierarchy is clicked, it always redirected to root page(i.e., clear the navigation stack containing outside visual hierarchy routes).

Comment: This issue is open in [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6855)

Comment: The work around in the issue doesnt work for you?

Comment: You could override `OnNavigating` method. Search for example of that in [XF Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, you mean to clear the navigation stack by overriding OnNavigating method, right? In such case, how is it possible to get info about whether destination root (TabBar shell object) route has navigation stack on it or not?

Comment: How's the workaround work for you

Comment: First, have you tried `Shell.Current.SendBackButtonPressed();`? [Though I think that won't help in this case.] Second, testing nav stack is what is shown later in that issue thread:  `if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
                Navigation.PopAsync();
            else
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//first");`. For more details, see [that comment](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6855#issuecomment-591721930).